# mongo-connector with neo4j_doc_manager seems to be hanging

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I have a currently empty MongoDB instance that I am trying to connect to a Neo4j instance (also empty). I have installed MongoDB, Neo4j, python, mongo-connector, and Neo4j Doc Manager, but I cannot seem to get past

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
```

I open Windows PowerShell as Administrator and start MongoDB with:

```
.\mongod --replSet myDevReplSet
```

which appears to start correctly. It indicates that it is waiting for connections on port 27017 and then goes on to "transition to PRIMARY" and "database writes are now permitted." So I open a second Windows PowerShell as Administrator and type

```
.\mongo
```

The shell indicates that it connected to test and shows

```
myDevReplSet:PRIMARY>
```

So then I type in the mongo-connector line (above) and am met with

```
...
```

And it just seems to sit there eternally. Neo4j is up and running through all of this.

I'm sure I've missed a very small, very crucial piece, but I can't seem to find it. I've gone back through all the documentation I could find and scoured the internet to no avail. All parts are installed with the default settings and ports. I've checked that both the MongoDB and Neo4j port numbers are correct. For reference, I'm using the documentation from [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/) and [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

I am running all of this on a fresh Windows 10 virtual machine with the latest versions of all five pieces of software (downloaded from the respective sites today). I created a json file from the CSV files included in the tutorial that comes with Neo4j (Northwind database files) that I was trying to load into MongoDB and then see in Neo4j. Unfortunately, I'm never getting that far.

Can anyone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything in the log file? What happens when you insert a document into mongodb?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but I can't even find the log file. And then I tried mongo-connector --help and that gave me an error "missing ; before statement." So I tried just mongo-connector, and that's giving me "mongo is not defined." When I insert a document into MongoDB, I can see the document in MongoDB but not in Neo4j. My Neo4j instance stays empty.

Comment: Did you init the replset: `rs.initiate()` in mongo-shell? The log will be called mongo-connector.log. Also, invoke mongo-connector with -v option for verbose logging mode: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/blob/master/docs/neo4j_doc_manager_doc.adoc#25-errors-and-exceptions

Comment: I did run `rs.initiate()`. I scanned the entire C drive and do not see a file mongo-connector.log. I tried the -v option and nothing changed. I typed http://localhost:7474/db/data into a web browser and was met with "No authorization header supplied." I realized I forgot the NEO4J_AUTH environment variable, so I added that to my system variables and restarted. That did not make a difference either. I'm just doing this as part of my Master's degree research, so if this just won't work in my environment, that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

can't enter in comment, but this is what fixed for me, if you are running from windows make sure SET NEO4J_AUTH in the same cmd before running rs.initiate() and mongo connector.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to run mongo-connector within mongo. You need to call mongo-connector from a new command prompt. mongo-connector is a separate program (that you might have previously installed via pip).